# How can i stop my activity from refreshing when i unlock my phone

Tags: android

I have activity that refreshes every time i unlock my screen. it also refreshes if the back light goes off and i tap the screen to turn it on. can any one suggest me how can i prevent my  activity from refreshing.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to go through some of the questions and mark a few correct answers as accepted, if you can - people will be unlikely to answer your questions if you don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "refreshing", but whenever the phone locks, it will call `onPause()` in your `Activity`.  When it unlocks, it will call `onResume()`.  If you have any initialization code in your `onResume()` it will re-initialize your app; thus making it seem like the app was "refreshed".  If that's the reason, then put initialization code inside `onCreate()` and you should be fine.

At the same time it is a good idea to save your app's last state in `onPause()` such as settings that your user may have selected.  Then you can restore them in `onResume()`.  The reason you would want to do this is so that if, for some reason, the phone doesn't come out of it's lock state (battery dies, is pulled, whatever), the state of the program when it was last used can easily be restored when it comes back.

Comment: thanks.. i think this will solve my problem. i will look into it and reply if it works.